What is meant by audible frequency?
Human audible frequency range is between 20 and 20kHz. Which frequency we are talking about? Is it sampling rate of is it which we get after doing Fourier transform?

The one after Fourier Transfer. Or more specifically  specifically the ones we get with a short term Fourier Transform with a suitable window length.  Sample rates of audio are typically 44.1kHz and 48 kHz.

But it is not intuitive. Suppose speaker is a drum that beats according to sampling rate then sampling rate is that frequency. What am I missing?

If you have a drum beating  at 48 kHz you wouldn't hear anything at all. All frequencies generated are too high for humans to hear. Are you familiar with sampling theorem and do you know what aliasing is ?

I am feeling sleepy. Can we discuss tomorrow?

I believe you have misunderstood a lot here.
The audible frequencies correspond to frequencies of “signals” generated by either physical processes or artificially. The sampling frequency, on the other hand, is the frequency with which you take samples of a continuous signal.
To try and generate some context I’ll provide a couple of examples.
Example 1 - Tuning fork
Let’s say we have a tuning fork and strike it on a surface and then bring it close to your ear. What you hear is an almost monochromatic (single-frequency) sound, with a frequency of $440 \, \textrm{Hz}$. I take for granted that a human with normal hearing will be able to listen to that, and yet, there is no sampling frequency involved anywhere here.
Example 2 - Sampled tuning fork
Let’s consider now that you use a microphone and a signal acquisition system (a “simple” audio interface is good enough) to record and digitise the sound. The frequency of the physical system has not changed just because we are trying to record and digitise it. However, here comes the question: How often am I going to sample the sound (to be exact, we sample the voltage output of the microphone, but for our purposes, we can assume an ideal converted, meaning that sampling the voltage is “identical” to sampling the sound)? The answer to that question gives you the sampling frequency!
Now, no matter what the sampling frequency you decide, the frequency recorded through the acquisition apparatus will not change! What is possible to change is its representation in the digital domain and/or your ability to discern this frequency from others after it is digitised. These two (and more) issues stem directly from the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem (I have linked Wikipedia, but no matter which signal processing textbook you open the theorem will be there).
To recap, we see two distinct notions of frequency here. One is the frequency that corresponds to the frequency content of the signal(s) (frequency of the tuning fork) and the other corresponds to the rate with which we sample these signals (sampling frequency/rate).
Example 3 - Sampled physical signal
This example does not provide additional information to the problem, but it is meant to show that the same principles apply to complex sounds with more than one frequency constituent.
Let’s imagine now that instead of a tuning fork, the sound source is a bat. Bats vocalise in the frequency range from about $10 \, \textrm{kHz}$ to about $150 \, \textrm{kHz}$ depending on the family/species. Now, let’s assume that the specific bat we record vocalises from about $10 \, \textrm{kHz}$ to about $50 \, \textrm{kHz}$ (possibly part of it being for echolocation purposes) and that our apparatus is capable of recording and digitising that sound without loss of information. Based again on the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem the sampling frequency should be at least $100 \, \textrm{kHz}$, something is possible to achieve nowadays (some “studio”/recording audio interfaces go up to $192 \, \textrm{kHz}$).
Let’s see what frequencies we can distinguish here. First of all, it is the sampling frequency which will most probably (and this is the case in the vast majority of the cases) be fixed. Let’s pick the $192 \, \textrm{kHz}$, which is available in many audio recorders nowadays. So, we know that we will pick samples every $\frac{1}{192000} \, \textrm{s}$, or $192000$ times per seconds. And this is all the sampling frequency tells us.
Now, we also have the frequencies present in the physical signal that is recorded and digitised. Like in the case with the tuning fork, these frequencies will not be affected by our choice of the sampling frequency. However, in this case, we can make another distinction in the frequencies present in the "physical signal”. Frequencies from $10 \, \textrm{kHz}$ up to about $20 \, \textrm{kHz}^{*}$ will be audible to humans with normal (or rather perfect) hearing. These frequencies are audible frequencies, or as we say in the audible spectrum/range. Frequencies above $20 \, \textrm{kHz}$ will still be present in the recorded signal, but we will not be able to hear them (many animals, such as the bat in our example, dogs, cats, birds, etc. can hear them though). These frequencies are outside the frequency range of humans and since they are higher than the higher audible frequency, we use the term ultrasound.
Frequencies in and outside the human audible range are in the recorded signal and will be there irrespective of our choice of sampling frequency. The former has to do with the sound that is either recorded (in our case) or generated/reproduced (in the case of reproduction or generation of signals), while the latter has to do with the acquisition/reproduction system, which dictates the rate at which samples are taken (recording) or generated (reproduction).
I hope this clarifies a bit the notion of frequencies encountered in a digital system. Please note, however, that everything is oversimplified here to try and provide an explanation and lots of details have been omitted. I would strongly suggest having a look at any digital signal processing textbook. There are many such good books out there; please let us know if you’d like recommendations.

I have some doubts can we talk in chat?

I believe you have to have at least 20 reputation to be able to write in a chat. You may want to propose an alternative way to chat or add comments here @Manohar
